# Index of the active list element angular 7

Tags: angular

How to get the index of the active list element in Angular 7 whitout *ngFor?

I have a code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li class="active">Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
```

and how can I get index (#2) of li with active class?

Comment: Can't think of an standard CSS way to do it, but maybe we can hook into some other process. What generates your lists / how are they generated?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element

Comment: or using jQuery you can use `.hasClass`

Comment: What do you need, the reference to the HTML element or an Angular element reference ?

Comment: This list created without *ngFor. I need to get from existing list the active item's id. I have an angular ts file with that html file where I can access this list. But how to get index position of the element. In jquery there have a function indexOf() to get the index of element in the list. How can I do the same with angular component in component.ts file?